# Pointer not adding my new values to my memory location of a variable

Tags: c++, pointers

`AddFive(int* Age)` job of this method is to add some value to my age.But it's not working

```
void AddFive(int* Age)
{
    *Age= *Age+ 5;
} 

int MyAge = 23;
AddFive(MyAge );
printf("My original Age is %d\n", MyAge );
```

Comment: Does your code compile ?

Comment: You are passing integer to a function that takes a pointer.

Comment: "It's not working" is not a useful problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to call your Method

```
AddFive(&MyAge );
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the method with the address of the vabiable --

```
AddFive(&MyAge);
```

because your function accepts address of an integer.

Comment: The terminology is wrong. You should be saying " Pass the method by passing the int by pointer".

Answer (score 0):

Well actually in your function definition of `AddFive` you are saying that a `pointer to int` should be passed as argument while calling `AddFive`, but this is not what you are doing while calling `AddFive` as `AddFive(MyAge)` where `MyAge` is a integer and not an pointer to integer.

Hence to resolve that mistake, you should try:

```
int MyAge = 23;
AddFive(&MyAge);
```

Comment: There's no need to intdoduce memory leaks. The question has nothing to do with memory allocation.

Comment: Well it would not have lead to memory leak for this short program. I just added that so that if he wanted to use create a pointer of `MyAge` from beginning that it would have helped him.

Comment: Oh, I must have missed the place where you called `delete`. Anyway, a pointer doesn't have to point to dynamically allocated memory, so there was no reason to call `new`.